# jquery and ajax page refreshing issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am fetching a problem though I know it's not a big issue, but something is different to me as I new. I have a page which has a list of records, fetching from a database. Now one button is there , after clicking the records, one pop up will be opened up along with some data. Inside that pop up one another link is there called "restore", whenever , that linked will be clicked out the database has been updated. Now up to this its okay for me. But whenever, I close the pop up, my list of records should automatically changed as some records have been restored. But I am not getting the result until and unless I do not refresh the page. so how can I do this, please help me ....

```
$(function() {
        $(".delete").click(function() {
            $('#load').fadeIn();
            var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var string = 'id='+ id ;

            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "restore-request-process.php",
               data: string,
               cache: false,
               success: function(){
                commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                $('#load').fadeOut();
              }

             });


             //return false;
        });
    });
```

in the restore-request-process.php page I just update the database and echo the id.

Answer (score 0):

After the database update, call a function to update the front end or simply reload page using `location.reload()`

Answer (score 0):

you need to have declared global function in parent window

```
function Update(){ 
//global function in parent, update div
}
```

on popup window call function

```
window.opener.Update();
```

that will automatic reload your div, and not all page, If it's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your listing format

```
<table>
<?php
foreach($results as $result) { ?>
<tr id="my_div">
<td><?php echo $result->name?></td>
<td class="delete" id="<?php echo $result->id?>"><img  src="delete.png"/></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

In restore-request-process.php write a query which fetch all the result from database and just echo the result like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

 echo   '<td>'. echo $row["name"].'</td>
    <td class="delete" id="'. echo $row["id"].'"><img  src="delete.png"/></td>' ;

  }
```

and onsuccess replaced all the content inside the my_div with response text
`CODE IS NOT TESTED`
for more references you can go through [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)